# How to organize Javascript within my Symfony project

Tags: symfony

I am becoming addicted to Symfony's separation of concerns, and I'd like to extend this philosophy to my Javascript. I am finding the view layers in my projects to be very reasonable divisions for related Javascript functionality.

What's the best way to organize & separate my Javascript? Ideally, I'd like to be able to add view-specific Javascript. I'm almost certain embedding the JS directly into the template is bad practice. I also know that adding a new `script` tag in each view is costly to the client.

What's the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some documentation about [assetic and asset management](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html). 
If you were able to quickly pick up the templating structure then this documentation is definitely for you.